# How to call Scalar-Valued function from Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on a project in which my BE is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and my FE is Access 2010 in accdb format.
I am trying to open a recordset that uses a Scalar-Valued function like so:

```
SELECT [ID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Comment]
FROM [table general information]
WHERE dbo.udf_StripHTML([Comments]) like '%Hello World%'
ORDER BY [ID]
```

When I run this from within SQL Server everything works fine, but when I run this:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim con As ADODB.Connection

Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
rs.Open strQuery, con, adOpenStatic
```

I get `Undefined function dbo.udf_StripHTML in expression`

I am assuming I'm using the wrong connection. If so - is there a built in property that I can get the connection from? And if that's not the case, what's the problem?

Note: [table general information] is linked to a table in SQL Server

Comment: Just to confirm: [table general information] is an Access linked table pointing to a table or view in SQL Server?

Comment: Correct it is linked to a table in SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the SQL Server user defined function by creating a pass-through query with a `DAO.QueryDef` object, as illustrated in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676579/2144390).