# Calling stored procedure using VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am working in Access 2010 user front-end with a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 back-end.

The tables in Access are all linked to the SQL server database.

I have a stored procedure that inserts new values (supplied by the parameters) into a table.

I asked a similar question previously and got a good answer [Calling Stored Procedure while passing parameters from Access Module in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248870/calling-stored-procedure-while-passing-parameters-from-access-module-in-vba)

I do not know how to find the information required for making a connection string (ex: I don't know the provider/server name/server address).

I found a question on here that stated "If you already have an Access linked table pointing to the SQL Server database then you can simply use its `.Connect` string with a DAO.QueryDef object to execute the Stored Procedure" - [Connection string for Access to call SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664139/connection-string-for-access-to-call-sql-server-stored-procedure)

I tried to implement this code. To pass parameters, I tried using a previous example.

I got the error

> call failed

at the line `Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)` (not to mention my passing parameters code is probably way off).

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblInstrumentInterfaceLog").Connect
qdf.sql = "EXEC dbo.upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

qdf.Parameters.Append qdf.CreateParameter("@BatchID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, BatchID)
qdf.Parameters.Append qdf.CreateParameter("@InstrumentName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, InstrumentName)
qdf.Parameters.Append qdf.CreateParameter("@FileName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, FileName)
qdf.Parameters.Append qdf.CreateParameter("@QueueId", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, QuenueId)

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Could anyone tell me what could be wrong with my code and why I am getting this error?

Comment: is this a standard Access database or an Access Data Project? i.e. are the tables linked via ODBC (standard database) or have you connected your data project directly to a SQL Server database?

Comment: I am not really sure I did not create the database I am just writing procedures for it.  Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Not sure for Access 2010, but things to look at...are the tables linked tables or do they just look like native tables? Under the File menu option do you have a Connection option where the connection to the database is set?

Comment: The tables are linked tables and there is no connection option in the file menu but there is a module that controls what database the frontend is connected to.  The databases are stored on the server.  I don't know if that helps.

Comment: That's all fine. I'll take a look and come up with something for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Victoria,

You can run a stored procedure using ADO, like below...

```
Set mobjConn = New ADODB.Connection
mobjConn.Open "your connection string"
Set mobjCmd = New ADODB.Command
With mobjCmd
    .ActiveConnection = mobjConn 
    .CommandText = "your stored procedure"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("your parameter name", adInteger, adParamInput, , your parameter value)
    ' repeat as many times as you have parameters

    .Execute
End With
```

To get your connection string, you can use the line

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblInstrumentInterfaceLog").Connect
```

in the Immediate Window and that should show you a connection string which you can use.

Would you try that and let me know if you have any problems.

Ash

Comment: The connection string might need to be different since CurrentDB.TableDef objects use DAO by default, and this connection is using ADO.  http://www.connectionstrings.com is a pretty useful resource for figuring out the necessary changes.

Comment: What is `Me.Connection` ? It thows error `invalid use of Me keyword`.

Answer (score 1):

Can also formulate a stored proc call that returns a result set as a select statement.

As per this example:

```
Sub Macro2()


'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    'Declare variables'
        Dim mySql As String
        Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
        objMyConn.CommandTimeout = 0
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        objMyCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
        objMyConn.ConnectionString = CStr(Range("ADOConnectString").Value)
        objMyConn.Open
        Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn


   ' call dbo.TotalLHCLoadingRate  Range("TotalLHCLoadingRate")

        mySql = "select dbo.TotalLHCLoadingRate ( " _
    + CStr(Range("MemberNo").Value) _
    + ", getdate() ) "
        MsgBox "TotalLHCLoadingRate SQL : " + mySql
        objMyCmd.CommandText = mySql
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        objMyCmd.Execute
        objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd
        Range("TotalLHCLoadingRate ").Value = ""
        Range("TotalLHCLoadingRate ").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        Range("TotalLHCLoadingRate ").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        MsgBox "TotalLHCLoadingRate  : " + CStr(Range("TotalLHCLoadingRate ").Value)
        objMyRecordset.Close
End Sub
```