# Call SQL Stored Procedure using Procedure clause

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am trying to build a database for IT device inventory. It uses an MS Access Office 365 front-end with a SQL 2017 backend.

In the database, we don't want to delete records, simply archive them to another table. To do this, I created a stored procedure in SSMS and verified that it does the job properly.

I want VBA to call this stored procedure. For this procedure, I need to pass it identifying information. In VBA, I am trying to assign the server name value from a form to a variable that I can pass into a call of the stored procedure. I found examples using the `EXEC` command but Access tells me I must use the `Procedure` clause.

```vb
Private Sub Command148_Click()
    Dim SrvNameVar As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strParm As String
    SrvNameVar = Me.SrvName
    strParm = "PARAMETERS [Server Name] As CHAR;"

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strSQL = strParm & "PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ArchiveServer [Server Name];"
    Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("SrvArchive", strSQL)

    dbs.Execute ("SrvArchive")
End Sub
```

The stored procedure that functions properly in SSMS:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ArchiveServer @Server nvarchar(30) AS
   BEGIN TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO FSC.dbo.Archive_Servers ([SrvID],[SID],[SrvName],[Make],
            [Model],[SN],[SrvIP],[RemoteMgmt],[OSID],[IsDP],[IsIEMRelay],
            [IsGUP],[DatePurch],[WarrantyExp],[RAIDConfig],[PrintSrv],
            [ConnectedToUPS],[VirtHost],[VirtMachine])
   SELECT FSC.dbo.Servers.*
   FROM FSC.dbo.Servers
   WHERE FSC.dbo.Servers.SrvName = @Server;

   DELETE FROM FSC.dbo.Servers
   WHERE FSC.dbo.Servers.SrvName = @Server;

   COMMIT;
```

Comment: FYI, the prefix `sp_` is reserved by Microsoft (for **S**pecial **P**rocedures) and should not be used for User Stored Procedures. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix#:~:text=TL%3BDR%20version%3A%20YES.,is%20still%20a%20no%2Dno.)

Comment: Thanks for the info @Larnu !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling stored procedure using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267080/calling-stored-procedure-using-vba)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you are conflating MS Access SQL dialect with SQL Server dialect. Only MS Access SQL queries supports `PARAMETERS`. However, you are attempting to run an SQL Server query, specifically to execute a stored procedure.

MS Access does allow pass-through queries to backend databases so you can adjust your QueryDef (defaults to Access backend) to connect to MSSQL database and then run `EXEC` command. All pass-through queries should conform to SQL dialect of backend.

```vb
Private Sub Command148_Click()
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim SrvNameVar, strSQL As String

   SrvNameVar = Me.SrvName
   strSQL = "EXEC dbo.sp_ArchiveServer @Server='" & SrvNameVar &"'"

   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("SrvArchive")

   ' ASSIGN ODBC DSN CONNECTION
   qdf.Connect = "ODBC; DATABASE=database; UID=user; PWD=password; DSN=datasourcename;" 
   qdf.SQL = strSQL
   qdf.Execute
End Sub
```

To effectively use parameterization, consider a different API, namely [ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-objects-and-collections?view=sql-server-ver15) (extendable to *any* backend database) instead of DAO (more tailored for Access databases).

```vb
Private Sub Command148_Click()
   ' SET REFERENCE TO Microsoft ActiveX Data Object #.# Library
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
   Dim SrvNameVar As String

   SrvNameVar = Me.SrvName

   ' OPEN DRIVER OR DSN CONNECTION
   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection         
   conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};server=servername;database=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password;"
   ' conn.Open "DSN=datasourcename"

   ' OPEN AND DEFINE COMMAND OBJECT
   Set cmd = New ADODB.Command     
   With cmd
       .ActiveConnection = conn
       .CommandText = "sp_ArchiveServer"
       .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

       ' BIND PARAMETERS BY POSITION AND NOT NAME
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param1", adVarchar, adParamInput, 255, SrvNameVar)
       .Execute
   End With

   conn.close()
   Set cmd = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I put it in place and it still kicks back Run-Time Error 3129. Invalid SQL Statement; expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE on the non-Parameterized code

Comment: Even with the required `.Connect` line? Error indicates you are not running a pass-through query. Note you are to adjust the parameters, not keywords, of connection string.

Comment: The Visual Basic editor is flagging the `qdf.SQL = strSQL` line

Comment: You need to assign `.Connect` before `.SQL`. Assign `.Connect` immediately after creating the QueryDef.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @ErikA. The ODBC connection defines which SQL dialect to apply for querydef. Mattyd, delete previous query before re-trying.

Comment: Thank you @ErikA. I will go try it out now.

Comment: It returned an error stating that I couldn't execute a SELECT query. Doing a little research, I found out that it is because it couldn't return a record.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pass-though query in the Access designer.

You can type in that command in the query (sql view). So, you have a pass-though query,and it will look like this:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_ArchiveServer @Server='test'
```

Save the above query. (make sure it is pass through query).

Ok, now your VBA code will look like this:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
   .SQL = "EXEC dbo.sp_ArchiveServer @Server='" & Me.SrvName & "'"
   .ReturnsRecords = False
   .Execute
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help! With all of the info that you provided, it is now working. To do it, I followed Albert's example creating the Pass Through query first and then appended his code with the information from Parfait and ErikA regarding the connection string. I then added a simple MsgBox command and a Close Form command to make it a little more "pretty". Here is the final code that worked:

```
Private Sub Command148_Click()

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SrvQryPass")
   .Connect = "ODBC;DSN=ODBC_17;Description=FSC;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=FSC;Network=DBMSSOCN;"
   .SQL = "EXEC dbo.sp_ArchiveServer @Server='" & Me.SrvName & "'"
   .ReturnsRecords = False
   .Execute
End With

MsgBox "Archived!"
DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, if you have existing linked tables, then the PT query also just like tables has a connection string. So, as per my example code, no need to bother with the connection stuff in code. In other words when you link and setup your tables, also link and setup the connection for the PT query you have. That way no connection strings or code in VBA is required. So, not having to deal with connection strings in code is  good idea, since if later on you change the linked tables and the database you are connected to? Then you not have to go find VBA code with connection strings either.